# Google Drive + Script throws permissions error even through I'm owner and granted permission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a basic script on a 12-hour timer trigger that loops through each of my Google Calendars by their ICAL URL, and downloads the ICAL for a folder on my Google Drive (for backup purposes). It throws this error

```
"No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 23, file "Code")"   (Line #23 is var folder... )
```

Running the script does download and save the ICAL file on the first run through the loop (and if I manually pass in each unique ICAL URL one at a time), but the error then terminates the loop. Seeing as how I've authorized access already and am the owner of everything here, I'm not sure what else I need.

```
var calendarsToSave = [
                     "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/inXXXXXXX.com/privateXXXX/basic.ics",
                     "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/XXXXX.com_XXXXXXup.calendar.google.com/private-XXXXXXX/basic.ics"
                    ]; 

var folder = '123xxxxxxxxv789';  // my gdrive folder 


function downloadFile(calendarURL,folder) {

   var fileName = "";
   var fileSize = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < calendarsToSave.length; i++) { 

    var calendarURL = calendarsToSave[i];

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(calendarURL, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
    var rc = response.getResponseCode();

    if (rc == 200) {
      var fileBlob = response.getBlob()

      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder);   // << returns a permissions error thus terminating the for loop
      var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
      fileName = file.getName();
      fileSize = file.getSize();

    }

    var fileInfo = { "rc":rc, "fileName":fileName, "fileSize":fileSize };
    return fileInfo;    

  }  // end for loop

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** You are also re-initializing a variable that *already exists* from the parameters and as a *global variable* so we can remove the parameter if you want to keep the global variable.

We can also move the place where you get the Google Folder object. It stays the same every time so we don't need to retrieve it again.

```
var calendarsToSave = [
                     "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/inXXXXXXX.com/privateXXXX/basic.ics",
                     "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/XXXXX.com_XXXXXXup.calendar.google.com/private-XXXXXXX/basic.ics"
                    ]; 

var folder = '123xxxxxxxxv789';  // my gdrive folder 


function downloadFile(calendarURL) {

   var fileName = "";
   var fileSize = 0;
   var gfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder);

  for (var i = 0; i < calendarsToSave.length; i++) { 

    var calendarURL = calendarsToSave[i];

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(calendarURL, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
    var rc = response.getResponseCode();

    if (rc == 200) {
      var fileBlob = response.getBlob()

      var file = gfolder.createFile(fileBlob);
      fileName = file.getName();
      fileSize = file.getSize();

    }

    var fileInfo = { "rc":rc, "fileName":fileName, "fileSize":fileSize };
    return fileInfo;    

  }  // end for loop

}
```

Let see where that gets us.

Comment: That cleared up the error, thanks. Now I think I need to add another for loop in there because it's only generating one ics file, not one for each URL in the calendarsToSave  array like it should.

Comment: Edit: I just needed to remove "return fileInfo;"  and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Your "folder" variable is outside the function, causing the data to be inaccessible to the "downloadFile" function.

Google apps coding seems to require variables to be in a function to be defined. I would recommend moving both "calendarsToSave" and "folder" to the inside of "downloadFile"

Here is an example that will return your error:

```
 var folder = '1HSFBPfPIsXWvFEb_AalFYalkPwrOAyxD';
 function myFunction() {
       var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder);
       var name = folder.getName();
       Logger.log(name);
 }
```

And here is one that will return the file name:

```
function myFunction() {
   var folder = '1HSFBPfPIsXWvFEb_AalFYalkPwrOAyxD';
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder);

   var name = folder.getName();
   Logger.log(name);
}
```

Comment: Just to let you know this is called "scope" it's fairly common in sane programming languages.

Comment: The variable is okay to be outside of the function. In Google Apps Script it is a global variable for your app. Not the _best_ way to do it but it's okay for small personal scripts. What's bad is re-initializing it within the function, creating a new smaller scope and making it confusing.

Comment: You can declare constants in the script body, outside of functions, and they are accessible at project scope. For example, defining a spreadsheet id to be accessed by a number of methods, or for the OP, a folder id.